# Replace counter field in large file with iterated value

Tags: bash, shell-script, awk, sed, readline

I have a huge text file with about 70k lines in it. My objective is to read this file, match a pattern ("Count"), and add or replace its value with an iterated number.

What I'm doing is :

1. Reading file.
2. Grep for the pattern Count.
3. If it matches, delete the pattern.
4. Append filw the desired pattern (Count = $i) in that line.
5. Increment variable i.

Here's the code

```
line_count=0
i=0
while read line
do
        line_count=$((line_count+1))
        if echo "$line" | grep -q "Count"
        then
                sed -i "$line_count d" /tmp/$rand_file1
                sed -i "$line_count i Count = $i" /tmp/rand_file1
                i=$((i+1))
        fi
done </tmp/rand_file1
```

The above technique takes about 25min to complete. Is there a way to reduce this time as I will be working with larger data files?

Below is the input pattern and file and expected output :

Input file

```
Count
Name = Sarah
ID = 113
PhNo =

Count
Name = John
ID = 787
PhNo =

Count = 123
Name = Mike
ID = 445
PhNo =

Count Now
Name = Max
ID = 673
PhNo =
```

Expected output file

```
Count = 1
Name = Sarah
ID = 113
PhNo =

Count = 2
Name = John
ID = 787
PhNo =

Count = 3
Name = Mike
ID = 445
PhNo =

Count = 4
Name = Max
ID = 673
PhNo =
```

Comment: can you paste sample input and expected output , that would be helpful to answer quickly ...

Comment: So you want to set up the line `Count =` with a sequentially increasing value?

Comment: @roaima yes, that is the requirement. Replace entire line starting with "Count *".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Replacing lines having Count with Count = its Occurrence

Assuming Count is the first word in line

```
awk -v c=1 'sub(/^Count.*/, "Count = " c) {c++}; {print}' /tmp/rand_file1
```

Assuming Count is the first word in line but can be preceded with zero or more white space, white spaces are not preserved.

```
awk -v c=1 'sub(/^[[:blank:]]*Count.*/, "Count = " c) {c++}; {print}' /tmp/rand_file1
```

Comment: Can I do a wildcard match also? Like if the line has "Count = 1234", how do I include this pattern also?

Comment: Also after every 14th match, the counter is getting reset to 0!!?

Comment: strange, let me try it..

Comment: for me it seems to be working fine , can you paste more..

Comment: Looks like its working. I typed the code instead of copy paste. But how to do a wildcard match. I saw that there are lines with "Count = 1234", "Count now" etc.. they are getting replaced as "Count = 1 = 1234", "Count = 2 = now".

Comment: Please add this to sample input in question, will update it...

Comment: Updated assuming whatever is there before or after Count keyword , needs to be replaced with Count = its count..

Comment: Note that it would increase `c` on a line like `Name = Count Olaf`. Since there can only be one substitution, you can replace the `gsub` with `sub`. Here you could do `awk -v c=1 'sub(/^Count.*/, "Count = " c) {c++}; {print}'`

Comment: yes, updated ....

Comment: @isaac Its not giving expected output...

Comment: @Bharat Yes, sorry. It should have been:  `awk '/^Count/{sub(/^Count.*/,"Count = " ++c)}1'`. But there is a better/shorter solution: `awk '/^Count/{$0="Count = " ++c}1'`.

Comment: @Bharat If you want to allow for leading whitespace, use internal awk ability of breaking lines into fields: `awk '$1~/^Count/{$0="Count = " ++c}1'` (assuming that a first field starting with `Count` is what is wanted).

Comment: @isaac, `awk '{sub(/^Count.*/,"Count = " ++c)}1'` wouldn't work as `c` in there is incremented regardless of whether the substitution is made or not.

Comment: @StéphaneChazelas Late to this party. The command has been corrected in my following comment(s). Read them.

Answer (score 3):

Parsing a text file in the shell is *very* slow and extremely error prone.  You are running `grep` once per line in the input file, and `sed` twice for every line that contains `Count`. Avoid doing this.

As far as I can see, this may be replaced by

```
awk '$1 == "Count" { printf("Count = %d\n", ++i); next } { print }' rand_file1 >rand_file1.new
```

This outputs the `Count =` lines with the correct increment when it hits a line whose first field is exactly `Count`, and passes all other lines on as-is.

Alternatively,

```
awk '$1 == "Count" { $0 = sprintf("Count = %d", ++i) } { print }' rand_file1 >rand_file1.new
```

which modifies the `$0` value (the input line) and prints all lines with a single `print`.

This last variation may be shortened into

```
awk '$1 == "Count" { $0 = sprintf("Count = %d", ++i) } 1' rand_file1 >rand_file1.new
```

See also "[Why is using a shell loop to process text considered bad practice?](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/169716/why-is-using-a-shell-loop-to-process-text-considered-bad-practice)".

Comment: The last `{print}` could be replaced by a simple `1`. Instead of using sprintf you could simply do: `$0="Count = " ++i`. The whole script would be: `awk '/^Count/{$0="Count = " ++i}1'`

Answer (score 2):

Short **`awk`** approach:

```
awk '$1 == "Count"{ $0 = "Count = "++i }1' file
```

The output:

```
Count = 1
Name = Sarah
ID = 113
PhNo =

Count = 2
Name = John
ID = 787
PhNo =
```

Comment: if you have anything other than Count in same line , it doesn't work...

Comment: @Bharat, you did not realize that your `/Count/` pattern won't ensure even **word** matching (along with *anything other*)

Comment: agree, let me fix it.

Comment: @Bharat, Ok, take your time

Comment: @isaac, not a big issue, see my update

Comment: Yes, that does it (+1).

Answer (score 2):

The obligatory `perl` answer:

```
perl -pe 's{^Count\b.*}{"Count = " . ++$i}e'
```

Comment: I think that RE match should be `^Count\b.*`

Comment: Think we need to change this solution based on the new edited input file.

Comment: If there are leading white spaces before Count this will fail. Maybe we can ask Perl to perform an automatic split into fields using white spaces will make Perl more helpful: `perl -pae 'if($F[0]=~"Count"){$_="Count = ".++$c." \n"}' infile`

Answer (score 1):

Using `sed`, with `seq` piped in for iteration:

```
t='Count'
seq -f "$t = %g" 70000 | sed -i -e "/^$t/R /dev/stdin" -e "/^$t/d" /tmp/rand_file1
```

---

Notes:

- `sed`'s  `R`*ead* command won't work in braces `{}`, so two `-e`s are needed.
- The `70000` could be any large enough number. When `sed` stops, so does `seq`, so the higher values won't even be created.

Comment: +1 for the clever seq trick

Answer (score 0):

Pending sample input files, I think this should work:

```
gawk '($1=="Count"){print "Count = " (++i); next;} 1' /tmp/rand_file1
```

Short explanation:

- on lines having `Count` as tehir first field: print a new count statement and increment number. `++i` will start at 1, `i++` will start at 0. In this case, also skip the rest of processing and continue to the `next` input line.
- on all lines (`1`): do the default action, which is to print the input line.

This should be faster since it touches every input line only once, in your existing solution, a match for `Count` copies the entire file around.

Comment: gawk: cmd. line:1: error: `continue' is not allowed outside a loop

Comment: Sorry, I pasted from the wrong command line, that needs to be `next`.